# Assign accesskey to a Flutter generated a tag

Tags: flutter

I have a TabView in Flutter for web to which I would like to accesskey

```
<a accesskey="D" ... >Donwload</a>
```

Please advice how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the current `Scaffold` in a `RawKeyboardListener` as shown below.

Then, use `key.data` to call your TabController and navigate to the releated Tab. `key.data` corresponds to a specific key.

```dart
RawKeyboardListener(
  onKey: (key) => print(key.data),
  child: Scaffold( ... )
)
```